# Advice needed on WPF TreeView and lazy load databinding with NHibernate

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, data-binding, treeview

I'm working on a project where I need to provide some treeviews to the users. So far I've managed to get my business objects and their persistence to a database fully functional.

I'm using NHibernate with SQLite3 to store the objects. The business object is as follows:

```
public class ErrorObject
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    private IList<ErrorObject> _errorObjects = new List<ErrorObject>();
    public virtual IList<ErrorObject> ErrorObjects
    {
        get { return _errorObjects; }
        set { _errorObjects = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm binding this to a treeview like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorObjects}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataModel:ErrorObject}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorObjects}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

What puzzles me, is the fact that, as long as I don't close the NHibernate session, I have full lazy loading out-of-the-box :o)

Can anybody advice if this is the way to continue? Or have I a flawed concept?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a good concept.

In NET 3.5 SP1 virtualization support has been added to TreeView (by adding support for hierarchical data to VirtualizingStackPanel).

As long as NHibernate fills the child list ErrorObjects when it was requested (first access to the getter) the tree should build up with lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's designed to work, so just be happy about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `ErrorObject` implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)/[`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) if you want the UI to be updated when the collection updates, **OR** make the `ErrorObjects` property to be of type `ObservableCollection<ErrorObject>`, [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) and [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)`.

I think the best idea for your scenario would be use an `ObservableCollection` instead of the `List`, if I am not wrong, the `ObservableCollection<T>` does implement `IList<T>` too.